# How to do a http call POST action in SharePoint Designer 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013 and would like to use the SharePoint Rest API to update some list item.

I know how to use the "Call HTTP request" action with GET method. But how to use the POST method?

Do I need to set the body as JSON?

**UPDATE**
I try to implement the post rest api as in the blogs in the answers. I send the responseCode and responseDictionary as an email to see what are the results. See below:

> **ret api url**:
> [https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/DMS-WF-Test-Infra/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TestKH4')/items(1)](https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/DMS-WF-Test-Infra/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(%27TestKH4%27)/items(1))

> **entityType**: {"type":"SP.Data.TestKH4ListItem"} requestBody:
> {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.TestKH4ListItem"},"Title":"aaaaa"}

> **responseCode**: BadRequest

> **responseDictionary**:
> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1,
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetById."}}}

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Dictionary variable to store and pass the body to SharePoint REST API in designer workflow.

Also, you need to pass the dictionary variable to the request and response headers which has below headers:

- Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
- Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose

Check detailed step by step information in below blogs:

1. [REST-API POST call using SharePoint designer workflow](https://www.codesharepoint.com/sharepoint-tutorial/rest-api-post-call-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow)
2. [SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflows and POST REST API](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2017/06/26/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflows-and-post-rest-api/)

Comment: Hi @Ganesh Sanap, see my update. I received a strange error.